# Spring cloud config server git-uri local file resolves to master

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

In my app's `bootstrap.yml` file i have placed this configurations

```
spring:
  application:
    name: arun-test

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: ${LOCAL_CLOUD_CONFIG_BOOTSTRAP:false}
        git:
          uri: file:${LOCAL_CLOUD_CONFIG_DIR}
```

I clone my properties folder from Github and then before starting the app, i turn my spring-boot app in to config server with below commands

```
export LOCAL_CLOUD_CONFIG_BOOTSTRAP=true
export LOCAL_CLOUD_CONFIG_DIR=/Users/arun/arunLabs/app-properties

./gradlew bootrun // to start
```

This works exactly fine.. But when i create a new branch and change the properties there to test something, the app always resolves to master-branch only and then it is still using my old configurations. Not going in to my branch

Not only that, it also replaces my file in the new branch with the one that is in master.

How to test it against my branch ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you're looking for is a client side request. Cloud config will serve all branches in your repository.

You can read in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#_locating_remote_configuration_resources).

You can either set the label value on your spring cloud Config Client

```
spring.cloud.config.label=newBranch
```

Or you can request directly to cloud config service

```
localhost:8080/{application}/{profile}/newBranch
```

Comment: the server by defauly resets the local git-folder to master. not allowing it to stay in the newly created branch